# Can the same virtual address 0x7DF8C3D2 in two different processes be in two different page frames?

Tags: memory, memory-management

While studying, I found a question my professor hasn't given the answer to yet:
Considering a system with a virtual memory having pages of 4KB and addresses of 32bit, can the same virtual address 0x7DF8C3D2 in two different processes be in two different page frames?
I was thinking it was false but I cannot give it a precise explanation nor understand the answer completely. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is "4BG" a typo for "4 KB", by any chance? "BG" means nothing I'm aware of and a page of 4 GB would take up the entire address space.

Comment: Yeah, sorry: it's a typo

Comment: What do you count as a page frame? Just the number? It's in the page frame 0x7DF8C in both processes. But each process has a different set of page tables, so do you count them as the same just because they are the same number? Some would say yes, some would say no. I think the term "page frame" is biased towards just meaning the number, which is obviously the same.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you. Unfortunately, the professor hasn't given any more detail than that, but in his answer, he just stated that it's true